# an algorithm to minimize the total excess

Tags: algorithm

Imagine that you have ropes which are 5 meters long. And you want to cut the rope in some certain lengths(30 cm,73 cm) for some certain times. I want to write a program that minimize the total length of the excessed robe and tells you how you should cut every rope. But, I don't know where to start and use what algorithm. Can you give me some reference? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems to be like a dynamic programming problem. BUT: What do you mean by for some certain times? Can you give examples?

Comment: It is like you have ropes 5 meters long and you want to obtain 30 cm long for 100 times, 43 cm long for 37 times, 39 cm long for 91 times... and you should obtain all these from 5 meters long ropes. I want to minimize the wasted rope.

Comment: This details are worth going in the question, and not remaining in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is so called `Cutting stock problem`.
Start by looking at this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_stock_problem) and follow Suggested readings. I remember we had this as a part of some course back at the university (although I can't remember which one), so you could have a look at coursera.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like homework, but I can still point you in the right direction. What you have on hand is an example of dynamic programming. From what I can understand from your question, you have a sub-case of the ever popular [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). Which is in essence an optimization problem of using the space on hand most efficiently, thus reducing the waste. Tweak it a bit to your own needs and you should be able to manage to get the solution for your problem.